# pandas map and timedelta with missing values

Tags: pandas, timedelta

Suppose I have the following dataframe (df)

[image: dataframe without time_diff]

I want to create a column that reports the difference between successive Timestamps for each ID, which is straightforward:

```
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['Timestamp'].diff()
```

which yields

[image: dataframe with time_diff]

Finally, I want to create another column `hours_diff` that reports the value in `time_diff` in terms of hours, given as a float. Ignoring microsecond precision, I tried

```
df['hours_diff'] = df.time_diff.map(lambda t: t.days*24.0 + t.seconds/3600.0)
```

as well as

```
df.loc[df.time_diff.notnull()==True,'hours_diff'] = df.loc[df.time_diff.notnull()==True].time_diff.map(lambda t: t.days*24.0 + t.seconds/3600.0)
```

both of which give me

> AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'days'.

However, if I run the command

```
print set([type(i) for i in df.time_diff]),
```

it tells me that the data types for the values in column `time_diff` are either `pandas.tslib.Timedelta` and `pandas.tslib.NaTType`, neither of which seem to be the `numpy.timedelta64` type.

Answer (score 1):

Series of dtype `timedelta64` yield `Timedelta` or `NaT` when you iterate over them, but functions like `.map()` or `apply()` will see them as `timedelta64`.

You can use `Timedelta`methods on the series via the `.dt` accesor:

```
deltas = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=10).to_series().diff()
deltas

2000-01-01      NaT
2000-01-02   1 days
2000-01-03   1 days
2000-01-04   1 days
2000-01-05   1 days
2000-01-06   1 days
2000-01-07   1 days
2000-01-08   1 days
2000-01-09   1 days
2000-01-10   1 days
Freq: D, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

deltas.dt.days*24.0 + deltas.dt.seconds/3600.0

2000-01-01   NaN
2000-01-02    24
2000-01-03    24
2000-01-04    24
2000-01-05    24
2000-01-06    24
2000-01-07    24
2000-01-08    24
2000-01-09    24
2000-01-10    24
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Still better:

```
deltas.dt.total_seconds() / 3600.

2000-01-01   NaN
2000-01-02    24
2000-01-03    24
2000-01-04    24
2000-01-05    24
2000-01-06    24
2000-01-07    24
2000-01-08    24
2000-01-09    24
2000-01-10    24
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion works perfect for the dataframe reported in the question with just a slight addition/modification:
deltas = df['time_diff'];
deltas_hours = deltas.dt.days*24.0 + deltas.dt.seconds/3600.0;
df['hours_diff'] = deltas_hours;

p.s. Sorry for the late response, I am very new here and was not expecting such a prompt and useful answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can just divide the timedelta64 by np.timedelta64(1,'s') to get the the delta in seconds. If you really want to get rid of the microsecond precision, just round it to 0 digits and divide by 3600 to get the delta in hours.

Actually, only the second to last line of the example is relevant, the rest is to setup the dataframe. (I changed the second line to have something with more precision which I can round.)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [{'ID': 'X', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 00:00:00', 'Quantity': 4},
        {'ID': 'X', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 01:25:00.435', 'Quantity': 7},
        {'ID': 'X', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 02:00:00', 'Quantity': 5},
        {'ID': 'X', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 03:00:00', 'Quantity': 5},
        {'ID': 'X', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 04:00:00', 'Quantity': 0},
        {'ID': 'Y', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 00:00:00', 'Quantity': 9},
        {'ID': 'Y', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 01:00:00', 'Quantity': 1},
        {'ID': 'Y', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 02:00:00', 'Quantity': 3},
        {'ID': 'Y', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 03:00:00', 'Quantity': 2},
        {'ID': 'Y', 'Timestamp': '2014-12-15 04:00:00', 'Quantity': 7},
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

df['time_diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['Timestamp'].diff()
df['hour_diff'] = (df['time_diff']/np.timedelta64(1, 's')).round(0)/3600

print(df)
```

The output:

```
          ID  Quantity               Timestamp       time_diff  hour_diff
        0  X         4 2014-12-15 00:00:00.000             NaT        NaN
        1  X         7 2014-12-15 01:25:00.435 01:25:00.435000   1.416667
        2  X         5 2014-12-15 02:00:00.000 00:34:59.565000   0.583333
        3  X         5 2014-12-15 03:00:00.000        01:00:00   1.000000
        4  X         0 2014-12-15 04:00:00.000        01:00:00   1.000000
        5  Y         9 2014-12-15 00:00:00.000             NaT        NaN
        6  Y         1 2014-12-15 01:00:00.000        01:00:00   1.000000
        7  Y         3 2014-12-15 02:00:00.000        01:00:00   1.000000
        8  Y         2 2014-12-15 03:00:00.000        01:00:00   1.000000
        9  Y         7 2014-12-15 04:00:00.000        01:00:00   1.000000
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, this works perfect. Apologies for the late response, totally new here, wasn't expecting such a prompt and useful answer.